# Stacking multiple line graphs in d3js without nesting data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I have a lot of data, extracted from a csv and sorted into neat categories, as follows:

```
return {
                time: d3.time.format('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S').parse(d.Time),
                conditions: d.Conditions.replace(/"/g, ''),
                temperature: +d.Temperature,
                humidity: +d.Humidity.replace(/[",%]/g, ''),    
                windDir: d.WindDir,                             
                windDeg: +d.WindDeg,                            
                pressure: +d.Pressure.replace(/"/g, '')
}
```

I want to achieve an end result similar to 'Small Stacking Multiples' (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9490516). Looking at the code, it uses symbols and nesting to achieve multiple graphs. However, my data isn't structured in the same way; I don't have multiple different symbols in one column. How can I replicate this result if I wanted to use all or some of my variables?

I did try fiddling with the nest() function, and achieved an array where the time is the key and temperature is the value:

```
d3.nest().key(function(d) {return d.time;})
    .rollup(function(d) {return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.temperature;}); })
    .entries(dataset)
```

...but that doesn't give me the multiple values per time that I'd like (and presumably need for the Small Stacking example).

To clarify what I have now, here's my domain/range/axis definitions:

```
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(10);
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(7);

    x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.time; })); 
    y.domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return Math.min(d.temperature - 5, d.absHumidity - 1); }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.temperature + 2; })]);
```

My svg.append:

```
var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g') 
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
```

Comment: Well what do you want to nest by? Do you have several arrays of data each of which should be a graph?

Comment: No, I want to 'nest' by my different data values i.e. temperature, humidity, wind direction etc. I'm not even sure nesting is the right approach; it's just the one used in the Small Stacking example, which is what I want to emulate.

Comment: Ok, so `symbols` in this example would be the list of names in your case, i.e. something like `var symbols = ['temperature', 'humidity', ...]`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff OK, managed to try this at home now. Having an array of symbols is fine, but the example uses something called 'symbol.values' everywhere which is not something I have in my code, and is hence undefined. I just need to know how to use my current data structure to generate a variable amount of line graphs... I doubt I can use the same sort of code as in the example, because of the completely different data structure.

Comment: Well you are using `symbol` as an index into your array, e.g. `d3.min(symbols, function(symbol) { return d3.min(data, function(d) { return d[symbol]; }); })`. And yes, this does make it more difficult and it may be easier with a different data structure, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: `Symbol` doesn't actually have a value for me... whenever I use it it complains of 'undefined'. Also, in principle, do I need to modify my x-axis domain from my default of `x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.time; }));` if I just intend to have multiple time x-axes?

Comment: No. It would help if you could provide a complete example.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Edited original post to try to clarify.

Comment: What I mean is that there are small-ish changes that need to be done throughout the code to make this work. If you posted a complete example (e.g. on http://plnkr.co/), I could make those there.

Comment: Added my code here http://plnkr.co/edit/XW6kDkZeRYWhav51Maes?p=preview It's not currently working because the data source (the csv file) isn't accessible, and I can't figure out how to add a 'fake' source... but all the code is there.

Comment: Well the data is quite important to figure out how to do it...

Comment: Added the data as a new file, not sure how to hook it up within Plunker though.

Comment: Something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/8IHZSyWEmspaHwuzUKE9?p=preview

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was going for. A few specifics; if I wanted to dynamically change which graphs are shown would I just have to remove or add elements from the 'symbols' array? Also, what if I wanted the dates to show only on the bottom-most x-axis?

Comment: I'll add an answer and explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no intrinsic need for the data to be nested, this is more or less just a convenient way to achieve what's desired in this case. For your data, you already have some kind of nesting, it's just less explicit.

The general approach is that the nested structure determines what's displayed. That is, for each graph there is one "thing" in the outer nesting. These are the different measurements in your case, so you need an array that contains those:

```
var symbols = ['temperature', 'humidity', 'windDeg', 'pressure', 'absHumidity'];
```

Everything else hangs off that. The most intuitive (albeit not particularly D3 way) to add one graph per element is to simply loop over the array:

```
symbols.forEach(function(symbol) {
  // ...
});
```

Inside the loop, the relevant datum is given by `symbol` as an index into the array of data, e.g.

```
y.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d[symbol]; }));
```

Everything that deals with the data needs to access it in this way. And that's basically it; full demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8IHZSyWEmspaHwuzUKE9?p=preview).

To change what's shown, all you need to do is edit the `symbols` array -- each element denotes an attribute name of a measurement to show.

If you want particular parts (e.g. the x axis) to show only on one of the graphs, wrap the code that creates it in an `if` statement that checks e.g. the current `symbol`.

Comment: Specifically for the selective x-axis showing; I want it only for the last graph of the set. I was thinking something like `if (symbol = symbols[symbols.length-1])` as the condition, but `symbols` the array isn't accessible once inside the array... how can I check if the passed symbol is the last one of the array?

Comment: Cracked it; rather than having an anonymous function as the callback, I made it separate because `forEach` passes the current array member, the index, and the entire array to the callback. So having a separate function with those three parameters enables me to check where within the original `symbols` array I am.

Comment: Your original check should work fine, except that you're using assignment `=` instead of comparison `==`.

Comment: In reference to editing the `symbols` array to change what's shown, how would I redraw the graphs? I've got buttons that change the array, but that doesn't do anything without redrawing, and there seems to be no convenient place to separate out into a function...

Comment: The easiest way would be to remove all the graphs and rerun the code to draw them.

Comment: How would I implement that? I tried putting a function around the entire chunk of code that does that (from d3.csv(weatherLog) all the way to appending graph elements) and calling it when clicking the button, but it didn't seem to like that.

Comment: That sounds correct in principle. If it's a complete working project you're after and not just something that can be answered in a question here, you can also hire me as a consultant (see my profile).

Comment: I am working on a project, but I was hoping to break it into individual questions (mostly involving zooming/panning on multiple graphs, as well as hover elements on the graphs).